# Difference between "meadow" "prairie" "pasture"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, vocabulary

I'm a bit confused about these words particularly "meadow" and "prairie". What's the difference?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Please edit your question to add the research you have done in your efforts to answer it. See: [Details, Please.](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)

Comment: Here is the start, copy and past the relevant definition from this dictionary and say why you are still confused  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/meadow https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/prairie  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/pasture

Comment: Another line of research is to use google image search (or another search engine)

Answer (score 1):

The chief use of meadow differs in British English from that in American English:

From the OED

> **Meadow**
>
> 1.a. A piece of land permanently covered with grass to be mown for use as hay; (gen.) a grassy field or other area of grassland, esp. one
> used for pasture. Also (regional): a tract of low well-watered ground,
> esp. near a river (cf. water meadow n.).
>
> 2. **Chiefly North American**. A tract of uncultivated grassland, esp. a low-level one along a river or in a marshy region near the sea; (also) a tract of uncultivated upland pasture. --
>
> **Pasture** 1.a. A piece of grassy land used for or suitable for the grazing of animals, esp. cattle or sheep; pastureland.

Prairie is as per Michael Lorton's answer above.

Answer (score -1):

“Pasture” is ground cultivated to feed livestock, especially cows and horses.  It typically smells, at least slightly, of their wastes and so is not particularly pleasant.

“Meadow” is a grassy area with few or no trees.  When close to human habitation, it is a place for low-key recreation like picnicking and lounging, so the implication is positive.

"Prairie" is the American grasslands, equivalent to “steppes” of Russia and “savanna” of Africa, and how it is received varies with the listener.  Prairie covers a huge section of North America, from the Mississippi River to the Rockies, more than three hundred million hectares, five times the area of France.  To people who love the prairie and the lifestyles it supports, prairie represents virtues like hard work, straightforwardness, and integrity.  For people who prefer the more urbanized coasts of the continent, “prairie” means ignorance, social aridity, and backwardness.

Comment: Actually, a meadow is a field of grass which is grown as a crop and mown to make hay in the late summer, to feed the livestock in winter.

Comment: @KateBunting — perhaps that it was that farmer calls a “meadow”, but people not in the industry would call that a “hayfield” and think of a meadow as something much less commercial.